# Error al conectar SQL Oracle g11

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle-11g

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error completo:** *Estado: Fallo:Fallo de la prueba: Litener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor*

el puerto en la interfaz web es "*1158*", se lo cambio a donde dice "*1521*" y tampoco conecta.

¿Qué le muevo al **SID** siguiendo la instrucción?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seguro que se conecta por SID y no por servicio ??

Primero verifica que el listenner no este con status Sleeep.

- 1.- Abre una consola CMD como administrador.
- 2.- Teclea : **lsnrctl status**

Si el comando se ejcuta satisfactoriamente, no es problema de listenner.

Si la ejecucion corre con error(Windows error 61), el problema esta en el Listenner.

**Solución:**

1. En la consola CMD, teclear: **lsnrctl start**  y Enter.

Con eso se inicia el listenner.Vuelve a intentar la conexion.

Si hecho el procedimiento anterior, sigue sin conectar, verifica que sea correcto el archivo ORA: listener.ora

> ../u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora

Abre, ORA.file y valida que sea correcto el SID, Host y Port.

Básicamente tu error es porque no están correctos los datos de conexión o listenner no iniciado.
También prueba el tipo de conexión a "Avanzada" y ahí loca la cadena de conexión completa y da en  Probar.

> Edito:

Si te muestra error: **No hay más datos para leer del socket**

- Abre archivo  $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
- Cambia  “(SERVER = DEDICATED)” a  “(SERVER = SHARED)”
- Reinicia la BD y el listener.

Comment: Dentro del ora.file está todo bien, pero sigue sin accesar, dentro del archivo encontré un nombre del SID, lo puse en el programa, y aparece "no hay más datos para leer del socket". El listenner no me dio problema, inició bien. aún no accesa.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta para el mensaje de error que mencionas : ORA-17410

Comment: No me funcionó, pero la tomo como aceptada para los demás y porque la información está muy correcta. Lo mejor fue desinstalarlo e instalar el 10g.

Comment: Buenas parce, cómo estás?. Hey hice lo que explicaste y sigo sin poder crear una nueva conexión :c, me podrías ayudar? gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 1):

no sé si alguien tiene el mismo problema, pero yo lo resolví cambiando el SID, de **"xe"** a **"orcl"** que es el que viene por defecto al hacer la instalación. Espero les sirva.

Answer (score 0):

yo solucione el error de está forma:

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
escribes services.msc y buscas el servicio de OracleServiceXE, boton secundario del ratón y iniciar.

Saludos!!

Comment: Yo el servicio OracleServiceXE le tenía activo. Pero aun así, le di a reiniciar y funcionó!